# How to specify arguments for editor in Midnight Commander

Tags: linux, midnight-commander, nano

I'm using Nano as the editor in MC. I would like it to scroll by 1 line, which is not its default behavior.

I've found that you can specify the option `-S` when you run Nano to enable smooth scrolling, but I don't know how to tell MC to do that.

How can I specify the options for an external editor that Midnight Commander uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited the file `~/.selected_editor` and added the `-S` option there:

```
SELECTED_EDITOR="/bin/nano -S"
```

It works as long as I don't run `select-editor`, which would overwrite this change.

**EDIT:**

Actually there's no need to use the command-line option in this case. Smooth scrolling can be set in `/etc/nanorc` with `set smooth`.